# Scroll Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scrolling

I face a weird problem in Windows 7.

 When scrolling in a webpage (using the up & down arrows or the scroll wheel) it suddenly stops and I have to click in any area in the webpage to continue scrolling. 

The same happens when also typing in a text area. It stops typing and I have to click again in the area to continue typing. 

I believed that the problem was with my mouse (a Microsoft one) but I unplugged it and the same happens with the touchpad of my laptop. 

So I suppose it has nothing to do with the usb mouse. Has anyone faced this issue before and has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because another program suddenly gets focus. You'll have to figure out which program suddenly gets focus. It could be a popup too. Once you find out which program gets the focus, find a way to stop it from getting focus. (such as a setting in the program, etc...)

If you cannot find any program, scan your pc for spyware and virusses.

Usually when this happens, look at your taskbar without clicking anywhere to see which program is now active. Is it still the program you had active, or is it another program?

Comment: I'll add - if you can't figure it out by watching the taskbar, you can close off or kill using TaskMgr the other open programs one by one to see at which point the focus stops being stolen. Then you know the last one was the program that stole focus.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will check those you mention.